# Hide new Blogger posts from appearing on homepage and make them visible only under a specific label?

Tags: blog, blogger, tags

I am using Blogger. I want to write some posts under a label, say "Puzzles". I don't want the posts to appear on home page of my blog (as they show up normally). I just want them to appear when some visitor clicks on the label "Puzzles," otherwise not. How can I do this without back-dating content?

Answer (score 1):

Once logged in click posting, then edit pages. Click create page.
You can then edit your page just like a post. A link to the page will appear in the in the sidebar when you click publish page.

Comment: I know that, but I want to use labels.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a template](http://blogtechtics.com/2013/06/hide-some-posts-from-blogger-home-page-updated.html) that adds this functionality to blogger.   How it works:

- When you want to hide a post from the home page, give it the additional tag "hide".
- The template has conditional logic when displaying the home page that puts posts with those tags in a special div
- There is a CSS rule that uses `display:none` on those posts on the home page so that they are hidden from visitors.

Answer (score -1):

I use Wordpress, so not sure if this option is available on Blogger.

I just backdate my posts a year or something like that. This prevents the post from showing in the homepage since I blog regularly (at least on the first page, which is all I am concerned about), but will still categorize the post.

Not a clean solution, but it's a workaround that works for me.

Comment: Backdating the posts is not what I'm looking for. :/